# Resolve Shared AppGroup GUID

Tags: ios, ios8

i'm developing a file browsing tool (for jailbroken iPhones) and would like to be able to resolve the GUID folder names within:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/*-*-*-*
```

I've managed to resolve the guids for the app data and bundle folders (using a few plist files) but i'm unable to find a plist which resolves the AppGroup guids.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use libimobiledevice library for resolving this problem.
Using this library you can get XML with apps properties (use instproxy_browse function).

In this XML you can find paths to app Sandbox (/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/...) and to it AppGroup folder (/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/...) if it exists.